# How do I change the default arrangement of the attributes in the upgrade attributes option on the main catalog page?

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I change the default arrangement of the attributes in the upgrade attributes option on the main catalog page?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the admin panel you have to go to:

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

Then clicking into each attribute you have to change position property which will determine its location on the list that you showed.